# How to split this string with preg_match_all in php?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to split strings like:

> Some description art.nr: 4457 72 1x ACOUCH 90X200 NICE GRAY (3 colli) 1x matras 85x205x12 2x matras 80x190x11 Some specs 14x Premium otherproduct 90x200x23 HR34

The result I need is:

1. Some description art.nr: 4457 72
2. 1x ACOUCH 90X200 NICE GRAY (3 colli)
3. 1x matras 85x205x12
4. 2x matras 80x190x11 Some specs
5. 14x Premium otherproduct 90x200x23 HR34

To make it extra complex, the first part is optional, but the other parts always start with '1x' or so.

I tried many regexp, but I cannot get it to work. I can use preg_split() with something like `/\s?\d+x\s/` as workaround, but that is really dirty, although it splits nicely.

Even when only trying to split parts 2 till 5, I can't get it right.

I have tried many regexp-patterns with preg_match_all() in php on the least complex string:

> 1x ACOUCH 90X200 NICE GRAY (3 colli) 1x matras 85x205x12 2x matras 80x190x11 Some specs 14x Premium otherproduct 90x200x23 HR34

The following patterns came closest:

- `/(\d+x\s+.+?)(\s+(\d+x\s+.+?(?!\s\d+x\s)))+/i`
- `/(\d+x\s+.+)(\s+(\d+x\s+.+))+/i`

I think it should be something like: `/((\s+)?(\d+x\s+.+(?!\s\d+x\s)))+/i` but it does not do the job.

And the simple ones like `/(\s?\d+x\s+.+)+/i` just returns the full string or only the first chars `/(\s?\d+x\s+.+?)+/i`

I tried these (and many other variants) on:

- https://regex101.com/r/9nhkxJ/1  (only works as preg_match)
- https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html

What am I doing wrong? It drives me crazy; this is really not my first regexp!

(and how to get it working for the full string with the optional first part)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: split using [\s+(?=\d+x\s)](https://regex101.com/r/kRlZ1d/1)

Comment: thanks! This works indeed!

Comment: thank you all so much for your quick and good answers. This really helped me out!! xxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use this regex for splitting instead of so much complicated ones?

```
\s+(?=\d+x\s+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wYagbF/1)**

**[PHP Code demo](https://rextester.com/CJNU85635)**

```
$s = "Some description art.nr: 4457 72 1x ACOUCH 90X200 NICE GRAY (3 colli) 1x matras 85x205x12 2x matras 80x190x11 Some specs 14x Premium otherproduct 90x200x23 HR34";
var_dump(preg_split("/\s+(?=\d+x\s+)/", $s));
```

Prints,

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "Some description art.nr: 4457 72"
  [1]=>
  string(36) "1x ACOUCH 90X200 NICE GRAY (3 colli)"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "1x matras 85x205x12"
  [3]=>
  string(30) "2x matras 80x190x11 Some specs"
  [4]=>
  string(39) "14x Premium otherproduct 90x200x23 HR34"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just split on

```
(?=\b\d+[xX]\b)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/EVc6cA/1/).

Answer (score 1):

A long-winded way of doing what Pushpesh' regex does:

```
$str = "Some description art.nr: 4457 72 1x ACOUCH 90X200 NICE GRAY (3 colli) 1x matras 85x205x12 2x matras 80x190x11 Some specs 14x Premium otherproduct 90x200x23 HR34";

$words = explode(" ", $str);
$i = 0;
foreach($words as $word){
    if(preg_match("/^\d+x$/", $word)){
        $i++;
    }
    $array[$i][] = $word;
}

foreach($array as $words){
    $split[] = implode(" ", $words);
}

var_dump($split);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "Some description art.nr: 4457 72"
  [1]=>
  string(36) "1x ACOUCH 90X200 NICE GRAY (3 colli)"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "1x matras 85x205x12"
  [3]=>
  string(30) "2x matras 80x190x11 Some specs"
  [4]=>
  string(39) "14x Premium otherproduct 90x200x23 HR34"
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the old-school version. ;-) Which always works ;-) Preg_() is much nicer. But thanks anyway!